# How to use same controller with but passing different parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 modals that use the same controller, but one of the modal does not need “user” dependency while the other needs it.

With the "user" as a dependency, the first modal displays while the second throws the error below in the console.

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userProvider <- user`

If I take off the "user" as a dependency from the controller, the second modal works properly but the first then throws the error below

`ReferenceError: user is not defined`

How can I use both modals with this controller?

**code snippet below:**

`Snippet for modal 1`

```
$scope.openUpdateModal = function(user) {
  $scope.is_edit = true;
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'permissions_modal.html',
    controller: 'UserPermissionsCtrl',
    backdrop: 'static',
    size: 'md', 
    resolve: {
      users: function () {
        return $scope.users;
      },
      is_edit: function () {
        return $scope.is_edit;
      },
      user: function () {
        return user;
      },
    }
  });
};
```

`Snippet for modal 2`

```
$scope.openNewModal = function() {
  console.log("getting here")
  $scope.is_edit = false;
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'permissions_modal.html',
    controller: 'UserPermissionsCtrl',
    backdrop: 'static',
    size: 'md',
    resolve: {
      users: function () {
        return $scope.users;
      },
      is_edit: function () {
        return $scope.is_edit;
      },
    }
  });
  modalInstance.result.then(function (user) {
    $scope.users.push($scope.user);
  }, function () {
    // modal closed
  });
};
```

`Snippet for controller`

```
angular.module('app').controller('UserPermissionsCtrl', function 
($scope, $modalInstance, CSRF, Permissions, users, is_edit, user) {

$scope.loading = true;
$scope.users = users;
$scope.currentItemTab = 1;
$scope.is_edit = is_edit;
$scope.permission = {
  permission: '',
  options_as_json: ''
};
$scope.errors = {
  permissions: {}
};

if($scope.is_edit){
  $scope.original_user = user;
  $scope.user = angular.copy(user);
  $scope.loading = false;
  $scope.user.permissions = [];
  Permissions.getUserPermissions($scope.user.username)
  .then(function(permissions) {
    _.forEach(permissions, function(p) {
      if (p.options) {
        p.options_as_json = JSON.stringify(p['options']);
      }
  });

  $scope.user.permissions = permissions;
});
}
else {
  $scope.user = {
    username: '',
  };
  $scope.loading = false;
  $scope.user.permissions = [];
  $scope.user.roles = [];

}
}
```

Comment: Its not an issue with the controller, I think, it must be an issue with the way user was defined! is it a service? how did you define it? can you include this code too!!!

Comment: Angular is trying to 'Inject' a value for user but can't because it's not defined anywhere as being injectable. I think you really want to create a service that you can inject and have a method of the service launch your modal based on the passed parameters.

Comment: @NarenMurali I have edited the code

Comment: @Hopez You updated your code, but you never told us from where `user` mention in this line `angular.module('app').controller('UserPermissionsCtrl', function 
($scope, $modalInstance, CSRF, Permissions, users, is_edit, user) {` comes from, Angular is expecting `user` to be a [`Service`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_services.htm) Please include the service if you already defined it! Thanks!

Comment: @NarenMurali I just fixed it.  included the code to the modal 2
        `user: function () {
           return $scope.user;
        },`

Comment: @Hopez Nice! was confused where that user injection even came from :p

Comment: Thanks @NarenMurali

Comment: @Hopez You're welcome :)